# Facing error while restarting npm , npm start is showing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to react ,I have tried npm start, after I closed my pc once, after I restarted npm start is showing error, I have tried adding start command to my JSON file , still its not starting, I have googled it , even I tried all the methods mentioned here in stack overflow , but its showing error all the time.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 `package.json` file

First under `\Covid 19 Tracker` folder

Second under `\Covid 19 Tracker\Covid_19` folder

Seems like First `Package.json` doesn't have `start` script.

If you are trying to start app from wrong package.json, you will get this error. You should `cd` into the inner folder (if you are trying to start react app).